# Java start another .jar in its own directory

Tags: java, process

I'm trying to start another java process that takes its configs from a relative path. My current code is:

```
Project
|-- src
|-- config
|-- SecondApplication
   |-- config
   |-- app.jar
```

And the code to run:

```
new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "app.jar").directory(new File("SecondApplication").getAbsoluteFile()).start();
```

This is not working as expected as the process still tries to get ins config from the main applications config instead of its own config directory. If i throw the configs of the second application into the main applications config its working but thats not desired.

Leaving the directory() part of and using `SecondApplication/app.jar` in the command has the same effect. Why is that and how to fix this?